# displaying custom message on custom errors in validation summary control on client side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I am using validation summary control to display error messages of asp.net validation controls.

There are some validations in page for which validation controls are not being used. I am using custom javascript and jquery code for these. Kindly guide how I can display messages of these errors in validation summary control along with asp.net validation controls.

Comment: +1 for the good question. What did you try?

Comment: Have not tried anything, actually I am not aware of Validation summary client side API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use the Custom Validation control. This control supports client side scripting (so you can still use your javascript code to do it) but still ties into the validation framework asp.net provides.

From the [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article, something like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function validateLength(oSrc, args){
   args.IsValid = (args.Value.length >= 8);
}
</SCRIPT>

<asp:Textbox id="text1" runat="server" text="">
</asp:Textbox>

<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat=server 
      ControlToValidate = "text1"
      ErrorMessage = "You must enter at least 8 characters!"
   ClientValidationFunction="validateLength" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: after trying several wrong answers around, finally it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick said you can add the custom validator controls in place of your custom javascript/jQuery code. And then accordingly you can add the summary validation control. Also you can change the error message in your javascript code. Please check the below code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatetxtLength(source, args)
{
    var txtVal=document.getElementById('<%=txtusername.ClientID %>').value;
    if(txtVal=="")
    {
        document.getElementById('<%=custxtValidator.ClientID %>').setAttribute("errormessage","Please Enter the User Name");
        args.IsValid=false; 
    }
    else if(txtVal.length>9)
    {
        document.getElementById('<%=custxtValidator.ClientID %>').setAttribute("errormessage","Username must have less than 10 characters");
        args.IsValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid=true;
    }
    return;
}
</script>

<div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="712px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                Validator Testing
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Please Enter your User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="custxtValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="User Name must have less than 10 characters"
                    Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ClientValidationFunction="validatetxtLength"></asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" HeaderText="Please check below validations:"
        runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" EnableClientScript="true" />
</div>
```

This might be useful for you.